# Firebase: Query inner child without knowing the parent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I want to know if there is a way to query based on inner child without having to know the parent in Firebase Database? Here is the exact situation:
 As shown in the image, I want to query the entire data snapshot where title = "bj", since I have pushed them automatically so Im unaware of the Key (or parent in this case). Im curious if Fb Query has anyway to look into the nested childs directly? TIA[image]

```
private void fetchPinnedLocationsForSearchbar(String key) {

        Query query = MyApplication.database.getReference("/pins/").child("title").orderByKey().equalTo(key);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.e("-->X-DATA-FROM-QUERY", dataSnapshot.toString());
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final BusinessModel pinItModel = new BusinessModel();
                    if (((Boolean) dataSnapshot1.child("ifBusiness").getValue())) {
                        if  
                            BusinessModel pinItModelTest = dataSnapshot1.getValue(BusinessModel.class);

                            Log.e("->PicCount", pinItModelTest.getPicCount() + "");
//
                            _data.add(pinItModelTest);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer from another post on StackOverFlow that suggested the solution should be something like:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pins").orderByChild("title").equalTo("bj").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Log.e("-->X--ChildAddedQUERY", dataSnapshot.toString()+"---"+s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```